# Sonar 4.2 huge database with mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

we have a virtual machine that hosts Sonarcube v3.3.2 on mysql 5.5.

With all our users, the database (sonardb) ended up being 30gb give or take.

Later we decided to also install sonar 4.2 on the same machine using the same mysql 5.5, but with a new, different database. (sonar42db)

With all our users, the database (sonar42db) is **285GB**.

I read on this link: [SonarQube : How to reduce size of measures_data.ibd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873974/sonarqube-how-to-reduce-size-of-measures-data-ibd)

that I could shrink the database by deleting mysql 5.5, importing the dump to mysql 5.6 and exporting the dump again.

Needless to say after many days of trial and error,  it didn't work. and now I have a 227GB db with mysql 5.6.   I did manage to shrink the data  to 18gb by compressing the tables, but the exported dump is still really huge and growing.

In theory it should be more or less the same size as the Sonar 3 database. Any ideas on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.

relevant changes in the my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9G
max_allowed_packet = 2500M
innodb_log_file_size = 4G

[innodb]
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_format_max = Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check = ON
```

Comment: You might find an answer here, but, surely you will find an answer on: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The sonar support page redirected me to here... http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/

Comment: I know, but dba.stackexchange.com is specific for database.

Comment: no problem, so should I delete and post again, or is there some sort of vote?

Comment: I just a common user like you, I think will be best for you to keep this one too.

Comment: wierd, there are no Sonar tags in dba.stackexchange.  Since we dont have a db problem with our other web apps, I think it's probably more related to Sonar.....